# What is the name for a simulated 'now' date in the past?

Tags: time-series, forecasting, terminology

In time series analysis we often set up a test where we forecast as if we are a certain date in the past. Is there name for such a date?

Example:
Monthly sales data from January 2016 till July 2021. Today we are July 2021. To test if our forecasting algorithm works well, we do as if we are January 1st 2021, forecast 1 till 5 months in the future and compare to the actual. How do I need to call the simulated 'now' date 'January 1st 2021' ?

Comment: I have seen *backcasting* and *nowcasting* used for trying to predict the current and recent past from earlier data, but they also have other uses.  I suppose *epoch* or *cuttoff* could be used as the date up to which earlier data is used for prediction, but they too have other uses, so you would need to be clear as to your particular intended meaning.